# PHP preg_replace number of digits

Tags: php, regex, pcre

i have this:

```
preg_replace('/(\d{1}|\d{2})/gi', '$1', 'some number');
```

If text is one digit number $1 returns one digit number, if it is 2 digit it return 2 digit number...., but I need to returned number was always been 2 digit:

```
1 => 01 
2 => 02
...
10 => 10
...
99 => 99
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Why not simply use `(\d{1,2})` instead of `(\d{1}|\d{2})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this one?use `e` modifier,execute php codes with `preg_replace` function,and whatever `str_pad` or `sprintf` would meet your requirement.

`preg_replace('/(\d{1}|\d{2})/ie', 'sprintf("%02d",$1)', 'some number');`

Answer (score 1):

Use str_pad(). It's a lot cheaper. http://php.net/str_pad

Answer (score 1):

why so complex? [**KISS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and use [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
echo str_pad($input, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: Look at comment in previous answer.

Comment: @kog you should mention this with question

Answer (score 0):

Please use `str_pad()`. The `e` modifier is DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.5.0 and should be avoided.

Comment: `str_pad()` has already been suggested in all the existing answers.  Your statement about the `e` modifier is valid, but it should be a comment on the answer posted by @Lake.

Comment: I completely agree, but Stack Overflow wouldn't let me comment on that because my reputation score is too low.

Comment: Reading the comments under diEcho's answer, the OP seems to have had some reason that it did not suit their purpose to use `str_pad` directly. (We can't assess the validity of that requirement since the OP didn't make that comment in their post, and the answer where the comment was made has been removed.) Why not update your answer to show a non-deprecated solution, and maybe earn a little more rep towards the comment privilege?